# dynamic flexbox layout controlled by javascript

Tags: css, reactjs, flexbox

I want to have 3 column in a row, but no each new row, when the item per row is equal to one, I wouldn't want the item to be 100% width.

```
const Flex = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
`;
const Item = styled.div`
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex: 1 1 27%;
  height: 30px;
  border: 1px solid black;
`;
function App() {
  const [num, setNum] = useState(0);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>{num}</h1>
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          setNum(num + 1);
        }}
      >
        add
      </button>
      <button onClick={() => setNum(0)}>reset</button>
      <Flex>
        {[...Array(num)].map(o => (
          <Item>{o}</Item>
        ))}
      </Flex>
    </div>
  );
}
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/distracted-hellman-jzv9i

for example the 100% should not be applied at num 1,4,7,10,13 and so on. I can know when the index is equal to 1,4,7,10,13 but how can I know it's on new row?

Comment: To clearify: If an item is alone in a row you do *not* want it to be full width but take only 1/3 of the space?

Comment: @trixn yes.....

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
const Flex = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
`;
const Item = styled.div`
  height: 30px;
  width: 28%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 10px;
`;
```

If you will give a fixed width to your item then it will not take 100% space of the new row.

Comment: how to give space between the items then? there's a reason I don't have a fixed width.

Comment: You can reduce the width a little and add the margin. I am updating my answer with those values.

Answer (score 0):

You can give your items a width of `33.33333%` and your container a width of `100%`:

```
const Flex = styled.div`
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    width: 100%;
`;
const Item = styled.div`
    height: 30px;
    width: 33.33333333%;
    border: 1px solid black;
    box-sizing: border-box; // required if your items have a border 
`;
```

Live Example: https://codesandbox.io/s/cold-leaf-6erlm

Comment: then I can't put margin between the box.

Comment: @Hanz You did no specify in your question, where margins should apply. You want them to be only between items or also around them?

Comment: between the box.